# Why does Tie::File add a line if a file is sorted?

Tags: perl, tie

I have this little perl script that is supposed to sort a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'fileToBeSorted.txt' or die $!;

printf "line count before: %d\n", scalar @lines;

@lines= sort @lines;

printf "line count after: %d\n", scalar @lines;

untie @lines;
```

When run with this input (`fileToBeSorted.txt`)

```
one;4;1
two;3;2
three;2;3
four;1;4
```

the script outputs

```
line count before: 4
line count after: 5
```

and indeed, the sorted file contains an empty fifth line. Why is that and how can I prevent that?

Comment: Don't know, but a workaround is to do `sort grep { $_ } @lines`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in a now deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774535/100754), this seems to be a known bug.

A temporary assignment to an untied list variable is a workaround

```
my @dummy = sort @lines;
@lines = @dummy;
```

but this still smells like a bug to me, and you should [report it](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Report.html?Queue=Tie-File).

**Update**: [Already reported](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=39196) (by our own [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami), no less).
Perlmonks discussion [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=710580).

Comment: Nice find on the report. +1

Comment: Credit [@Squeezy's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2137516/squeezy) deleted answer for links to bug report and perlmonks.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [related PerlMonks discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=710580), `@lines = ((), sort @lines);` can be used to work around the bug.